# In the building tool `parcelJs` : generated code that can't run

Tags: javascript, build, parcel, parceljs

when parcel compile my code it build js file started like this :

```
"use strict";

// modules are defined as an array
// [ module function, map of requires ]
//
// map of requires is short require name -> numeric require
//
// anything defined in a previous bundle is accessed via the
// orig method which is the require for previous bundles

require = function (_require) {
  function require(_x, _x2, _x3) {
    return _require.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  require.toString = function () {
    return _require.toString();
  };

  return require;
}(function (modules, cache, entry) {
...
```

that code can't run because it try to define variable `require` without `var|let|const` in "use strict" mode .

So my qustion is : *why it generate bad code like that ?*

Answer (score 0):

So in [this tread](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/40) they say that upgrade node to 8.0.0 or above solve the problem.

In a funny way BTW... it magically remove the `use strict` from the generated file